# MySQL Select records not related to a certain record

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, sorry if this is a repost, I really don't know how to word what I'm looking for to really search for it.

I have 3 tables:

```
Amenities:
AmenitiesID
Name

resort_amenities
ResortAmenitiesID
ResortID
AmenityID

resorts
ResortID
ResortName
and so on...
```

I am working on the code that links the amenties to the resort, and saved in resort_amenities.

What I want is to have a jQuery modal dialog come up with all the amenities from the amenities table, that aren't already linked to that resort.

Right now in my ajax call I pass the resort id, to be used in the sql somewhere.

I believe I need a union but have never built one, out side of school years ago.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want, for a specific resort, the set of amenities not associated with that resort:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * -- get all those Amenities
FROM Amenities
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- that we can't find a counter-example for
  SELECT AmenitiesID 
  From resort_amenities 
  WHERE ResortID = <the resort id>
  AND Amenities.AmenitiesID = resort_amenities.AmenitiesID
)
```

This is a set substraction, of `S = S1 - S2`, where `S1` is the set of all amenities, and `S2` is the set of amenities that are already linked to that resort.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, you could try:

```
SELECT * FROM Amenities a
INNER JOIN resort_amenities ra
    ON a.AmenitiesID = ra.AmenityID
WHERE ra.ResortID <> your_resort_id
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Amenities a
LEFT JOIN resort_amenities ra
    ON a.AmenitiesID = ra.AmenityID
WHERE ra.ResortID IS NULL 
   OR ra.ResortID <> your_resort_id
```

Comment: That is close, but only returning the data in resort_amenities that does not have the ResortID of your_resort_id.  What I want to do is select everything from amenities that is not already in resort_amenities and has the resort_amenities.ResortID of your_resort_id. I hope that helps.

Comment: thats close, but it is spitting out all the data, instead of just the amenities data.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @guyfromfl: I use `SELECT * FROM Amenities` so how is it possible that you get _all the data_ not contained in amenities table? I'm confused...

Comment: Not exactly sure, copied pasted and hard coded the id...thats all I did... Thanks for the help anyway!